# Load html5 canvas publish of animate cc multiple times

Tags: javascript, canvas, createjs, animate-cc

The publish output of Animate CC gives html file and js file. I want to draw the same drawing two times in the same canvas. From this [example](http://x-simple-flahtml.kisla.com/simple_canv.html), i want to have output as[image]

How can i change the javascript to achieve this without having two canvas tag? I want to have numerous instance of it in single canvas tag.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to achieve the image above, you can simply create two instances of `simple_canv` class.

Try this:

```
var canvas, stage, exportRoot;

function init() {

 canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 exportRootLeft = new lib.simple_canv();
 exportRootRight = new lib.simple_canv();
 exportRootRight.x = 555;

 stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
 stage.addChild(exportRootLeft, exportRootRight);
 stage.update();
 stage.enableMouseOver();

 createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
 createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);


 init_app()
```

}

Also, remember to increase the width of your canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
            Your browser does not support the canvas element.
        </canvas>

        <script>
            var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

            var ctx1 = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var ctx2 = canvas.getContext("2d");

            ctx1.fillStyle = "red";
            ctx1.fillRect(0,0,50,50);

            ctx2.fillStyle = "blue";
            ctx2.fillRect(50,0,50,50);
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

You can then change what you render.